# Angular 4 different token same Implemetation

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular 4 app that is broken down into different feature. So I have a shopping feature with all its components and billing feature with all its component.

However, I have an issue with configuration. I would like to share configuration between multiple feature of the app. My configuration is different for each feature so I created a base config class and inherit from it.

However in my app.module is did a registration such as below.

```
{ provide: BillingModuleConfig, useClass: ConfigService },
{ provide: ShoppingConfig, useClass: ConfigService }
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: configServiceFactory,
  deps: [ShoppingConfig],
  multi: true
}
```

However, this does not work for the BillingModuleConfig. Which implies when I inject BIllingConfig in the section I need it from I cannot get the config setting. Is there a reason why this would not work?  My ConfigServiceFactory is the  an external function that load the config file as below.

```
export function configServiceFactory(config: ConfigService) {
  return () => config.load();
}
```

The config.load method loads all the configuration into a class that inherits from  both ShoppingConfig and BillingConfig.

The config.load implementation is

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { BillingModuleConfig} from '@razor/Billing';
import { ShoppingConfig } from '@razor/shopping';
import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

abstract class Settings implements BillingModuleConfig, ShoppingConfig {
 public ShoppingAPIUrl: string;
  public BillingApiUrl: string;

}

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService implements Settings {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public load() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http
        .get<Settings>(environment.configFileName)
        .subscribe((config: AppSettings) => {
          this.ShoppingAPIUrl= config.ShoppingAPIUrl;
          this.BillingApiUrl= config.BillingApiUrl;
          resolve(true);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that `config.load` assigns fetched configuration to `ConfigService` class instance, it will work only for provider token that was specified as a dependency for `APP_INITIALIZER`, which is `ShoppingConfig`.

In order for the configuration to be fetched in `BillingModuleConfig`, it should be specified, too:

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: configServiceFactory,
  deps: [ShoppingConfig],
  multi: true
},
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: configServiceFactory,
  deps: [BillingModuleConfig],
  multi: true
}
```

However, this will result in two requests. To avoid this, the most simple way is to use `ConfigService` everywhere. If `BillingModuleConfig` and `ShoppingConfig` were introduced because the configuration is currently combined but supposed to be divided later, they can reuse a common instance:

```
ConfigService,
{ provide: BillingModuleConfig, useExisting: ConfigService },
{ provide: ShoppingConfig, useExisting: ConfigService },
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: configServiceFactory,
  deps: [ConfigService],
  multi: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have just tried this and it works partially for some but not all cases . I am not sure if  it is my implementation. I am using  the injection of config in the  {
      provide: ErrorLoggingService,
      useClass: ErrorLoggingService,
      deps: [LoggingModuleConfig]
    },   but this is not working not sure its because I am providing this to the  GlobalErrorHandler. As it seems that loads first before APP_INITIALIZER.

Comment: What does 'partially' mean? This depends on how ErrorLoggingService and LoggingModuleConfig work, I guess, they aren't presented in the question.

Comment: Apologies my fault. I though it should extrapolate into the same. I have the same use case in different part of the app which would have been to big to paste above so I just added a watered down version. What I meant by partially is that all the feature that need the config are working but the GlobalErrorHandler is not  which I left out.

Comment: If the case differs from the one you've already posted, I'd suggest to ask another question that reflects the problem.